# Different records on different pages

Tags: php, mysql

Given is my php code to get 1 record per page.However I get same info even if  I pass different action value in url? why is that so ?

```
 <?php

    if(!isset($_GET['action']))
         $_GET['action'] = 'view';
    switch($_GET['action']){

        case 'prev':
            $q = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id='aamir' ORDER BY id DESC " ;
        echo "prev";
            break;

        case 'next':
            $q = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id='aamir' ORDER BY id ASC " ;
           echo "next"; 
     break;

        case 'view':
            $q = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id='aamir'"; echo "view";
            break;

        default:
            throw new \Exception('Illegal action value');

    }
      $result1=mysql_query($q,$con);
     if (!($result1) )
     {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
     }
     else
     {
        $values1= mysql_fetch_array($result1);
     }
    echo $values1['srno'];
    mysql_close($con); ?>
```

For eg action=prev must display 11th record, action=next must display 13th record.Assuming current record is 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a "current record ID" in your view page request.

Your URL should look something like `page.php?record=12`. Then the query needs to be looking for the referenced record:

**PHP**

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id='aamir' AND record_id='".$_GET['record']."'";
```

Obviously you would need to escape the variables too.

Your `next` and `previous` links would then contain the relevant ID of the next and previous records (if available), doing away with the need for the use of cases, since everything will be handled by the "default" VIEW case.

Answer (score 0):

You can add limit syntax to each query
eg :

```
case 'prev':
        $q = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id='aamir' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT currentpage-1, currentpage, " ;
    echo "prev";
        break;

    case 'next':
        $q = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id='aamir' ORDER BY id ASC  LIMIT currentpage, currentpage+1 " ;
       echo "next"; 
 break;

    case 'view':
        $q = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id='aamir' LIMIT currentpage, currentpage ""; echo "view";
        break;
```